# to call a function in other one

Tags: objective-c

Hi
    I have following function in a file  i want to call it inside another method of same class the second

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  // Issue vibrate
  AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);

  // Also issue visual alert
  UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
       initWithTitle:@"Screen Touched!"
       message:nil
       delegate:nil
       cancelButtonTitle:nil
       otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
  [alert show];
  }

i want to call it inside another method of same class the second function is called with the button press the second method is

-(IBAction)resetBet:(id)sender
{
      //call function here....
      //some code......
}
Basically what i am tring to do is to make device vibrate when button click
please tell me how to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

[self resetBet:nil];

should call the resetBet method.. or you can use an object like a button instead of the "nil".
Hope that's what you meant..

Answer (score 0):

Do what stackr said :D or use a selector.